# "Wrote it wrong" or "wrote it wrongly"?

Tags: grammaticality, adverbs

Which is grammatically correct?

> - He wrote it **wrong**.
> - He wrote it **wrongly**.

Comment: @TrevorD The question is not so much as finding a better alternative as it's about the grammaticality of using *wrongly* in place of *wrong. By the way, what's wrong with "He wrote it wrong", or even "He wrote it wrongly" for that matter?

Comment: "I pointed out that all students, even me when I was her age, make this mistake, but I made her correct it every time she **wrote it wrong**." (Elizabeth Anne Masciale - 1996; "And if **we wrote it wrong**, I am sorry. Mr. DEFAZIO. In any case, I am new to this subcommittee. " (Cruises-to-Nowhere Act of 1999 p.42); "So I checked my facts — without realizing it, in the same reference book I had used when I first **wrote it wrong**." (Emory M. Thomas - 1999) [emphasis mine; all referencess from GoogleBooks]

Comment: "... but, my dear young lady, **you wrote it wrongly** and could even do yourself harm as a result." (Dostoyevsky, et al - 1994); "But I just cannot understand how **we wrote it wrongly**. I want you to write it out for me word for word. " (Communications Act of 1994); "...the scribes of both the available manuscripts of this play were puzzled about this word and read it or wrote it wrongly..." (Indian Linguistics - Vol. 21-24 - p.124) [notes: as in previous comment.]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is "wrongly" used correctly below?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/297846/is-wrongly-used-correctly-below)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Any good dictionary should tell you that *wrong* can function as an adverb.  Your first sentence is fine.

I would accept your second sentence grudgingly, but it's definitely a second-class citizen.  It smacks of hypercorrection, sounding somewhat stiff and unnatural.  I think that if a native speaker was afraid that *wrong* was wrong, which it's not, they'd be more likely to go for a word like *incorrectly*, which is marked by form as an adverb with the suffix *-ly*.  (*Wrongly* is also marked with *-ly*, of course, but I think it sounds a little silly in place of *wrong*.)

So they're both grammatically correct, but the second sentence is (in my opinion) unnatural and should be avoided.

Comment: +1 For stating both relevant points. Most do not know of the adverbial *wrong*; even fewer understand why *wrongly* is a hypercorrection, not ungrammatical.

Comment: +1 for exactly the reasons stated by Kris, even though I couldn't have pointed them out.

Comment: @Kris: I'm not sure what you mean by "most do not know" there. It's feasible "most" Anglophones don't actually know the exact terminological distinctions made by *adverbial/adjectival*, but practically every infant will grow up familiar with the usage *"You're doing/saying it **wrong**"*. So they'll obviously know how to use *wrong* "adverbially", even if they don't know how to describe such usage in grammatical terms.