# Is "wrongly" used correctly below?

Tags: word-usage, meaning

> He counted money **wrongly** more than the amount I gave.

In the sentence above what I tried to say is that I gave someone fifty one hundred dollars bills, but he counted them as 52 bills instead as a result of the situation. Is the sentence above correct?

Comment: I also wonder. I guess native speakers will say he counted more than the money I gave.

Comment: Proof-reading is off-topic - but the _total_ he reached was more than the amount you had given him.

Comment: Or 'the amount he counted was more than I gave him', or 'he counted more bills/money than I gave him'.

Comment: [correction: Is **the** meaning of the sentence below correct?]

Comment: I think that adverbs that don't function in a regular manner deserve special consideration. This is one of them.

Comment: Related: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/7774/wrote-it-wrong-or-wrote-it-wrongly https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/82735/what-am-i-doing-wrong-ly

Answer (score 2):

He counted money wrongly more than the amount I gave.

is semantically incorrect:

He counted **the** money incorrectly or inaccurately. It was more than the amount I gave him.

**wrongly** is not used in the same way as incorrectly or inaccurately.

**Numbers are said to be incorrect (not correct) or inaccurate (not accurate)**.

The **adverb wrongly** is used with verbs such as think or believe:
He **wrongly thought** she left the door open.
Or: They **wrongly believed** the Caprivi Strip was in South Africa.

The adjective **wrong** is used as a regular adjective:
His answer was wrong.
That is the wrong answer.

Comment: So if I say “He counted the money incorrectly more than the amount I gave” would it give the meaning I tried to say.

Comment: @languagelearner Please do not make me repeat myself.  No, it is not correct. This would be: He counted the money as more than I gave him.

Comment: "wrong" is also an adverb, which causes a lot of confusion. "Hey! you counted that wrong. We agreed on 30 chickens, not 28."

Comment: @ColleenV Thanks, you are right [ha ha.].

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not correct. The closest correct sentence you can make from this is:

> He incorrectly counted more money than I actually gave him.

"Wrongly" and "incorrectly" are often synonymous, but not always, and not in this case.

- "He incorrectly counted" means that he made a mistake in his count.
- "He wrongly counted" means that he made a mistake by counting the money. The counting itself was the mistake. He shouldn't have counted it.

That being said, because of the continuation of the sentence, most people will understand what you mean if you had used "wrongly".

I removed "the amount" because it's unnecessary and a bit stilted, money is inherently understood to express an amount, especially if you're already quantifying the amount of money use by using "more".

"Actually" doesn't have to be in the sentence, but it is idiomatic here. It's used to further stress that there is a difference between the real amount and the mistaken amount.